# Unit test case fails in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xctest

When I run my unit test cases in xcode 6.3 it gives me an error saying

> `ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for
>   MacOSX file
>   '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest'
>   for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`.

The unit tests are working in the developer system but not in my server mac machine. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it out myself. It's a bug in xcode. Just uninstall xcode and remove files in path `~/Library/Developer/Xcode` . Then reinstall xcode and the error is gone.